# I am building the LEGO 42131 D11 dozer and some of the parts are moving in reverse when testing

Tags: technic, building, motor, gears

I am building the [D11 dozer](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=42131-1) and some of the tests like 2 and 4 are moving the parts in the opposite direction that they are supposed to be going. I took apart the entire build and rebuilt it and the same problem is still happening.

[image: 42131]

Comment: Could you please tell what tests #2 and #4 are for?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but turns out the app graphics are just wrong. Completed the build and it works perfectly fine.